# NDEigenvalues syntax

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

The internal documentation on NDEigenvalues is a bit unclear.  I want to solve two coupled eigenvalue equations in 2D for two coupled eigenfunctions. The problem is of the form:

```
LinOp1[ u[x,y], v[x,y] ] ==  eval u[x,y]

LinOp2[ u[x,y], v[x,y] ] ==  eval v[x,y]
```

where `LinOp1` and `LinOp2` are linear combinations of derivatives of the functions `u[x,y]` and `v[x,y]`.  The documentation implies that this is possible, because it discusses coupled systems with a syntax giving the list of linear differential operators and a list of functions.  But it's not clear in the documentation how Mathematica "knows" the eigenfunction on the RHS for the first operator is `u[x,y]`, and the second one is `v[x,y]`.  Is it just a matter of the order in the list of arguments?  Can anyone point me to a sample of a coupled system solved with NDEigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, it is given by the order of the second argument. An example from the documentation is the last problem under "Properties & Relations": `NDEigenvalues[{D[u[t, x], t] == v[t, x], 
  D[v[t, x], t] == Laplacian[u[t, x], {x}]}, {u[t, x], 
  v[t, x]}, t, {x, 0, Pi}, 6]`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I took the liberty of using your example in my answer. I hope that is OK?

Comment: @user21 Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
NDEigenvalues[{D[u[t, x], t] == v[t, x], 
  D[v[t, x], t] == Laplacian[u[t, x], {x}]}, {u[t, x], 
  v[t, x]}, t, {x, 0, Pi}, 6]

{9.12781*10^-18 - 1.27262*10^-7 I, 
 9.12781*10^-18 + 1.27262*10^-7 I, -1.87511*10^-20 - 
  1. I, -1.87511*10^-20 + 1. I, 2.74571*10^-17 - 2.00001 I, 
 2.74571*10^-17 + 2.00001 I}
```

is the same as this:

```
NDEigenvalues[{v[x], Laplacian[u[x], {x}]}, {u[x], v[x]}, {x, 0, Pi},
  6]

{9.12781*10^-18 - 1.27262*10^-7 I, 
 9.12781*10^-18 + 1.27262*10^-7 I, -1.87511*10^-20 - 
  1. I, -1.87511*10^-20 + 1. I, 2.74571*10^-17 - 2.00001 I, 
 2.74571*10^-17 + 2.00001 I}
```

In the [Applications -> Structural Mechanics section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) is another example.

I hope that helps.